# Suspend process to hard drive

Tags: suspend, kde

When I suspend a process via KSysGuard, I right click on the process, and hit 'suspend', I do not see any difference in RAM consumption. I am wondering if it is possible to make it so that suspended processes' RAM gets transferred to SWAP or something so that unused programs do not take up precious RAM. People might say, "Why don't you just close the program?" Well I don't want to close programs and have to re-open them later. It is very convenient to just suspend them and then continue them later when I need them. This seems like something that would be easily done. To my knoladge, SWAP is used when there is not enough RAM so unused stuff gets moved to the hard disk. I am running Kubuntu 14.04.